# What is meant by the notation $\mathbb{R}^{p \vert q}$?

Tags: notation, differential-topology

What is meant by the notation $\mathbb{R}^{p \vert q}$?

I am coming across this in a set of notes but I have not seen this notation used before.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this notation used mainly by physicists (e.g. in talks by Witten).  I think it is notation for *superspace*, e.g. as discussed 
[here in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superspace).